# Change the time that a picture was taken

Tags: windows-8.1, metadata, pictures

I have a bunch of pictures and I need to change the time on some of them. I'm using Windows 8.1.

The `Details pane` shown and I've selected one of the pictures in question, however when I click on the `Date taken` field, it only allows me to change the date, not the time. I've included a couple images below to show this

Is it possible to change the date of a picture in Windows 8.1? Thanks.

On the left is how the `Date taken` field is displayed to the user, and on the right is the only edit option you get when you click on the field.

[image: Change date not possible]

Answer (score 1):

Although not the easiest solution this is possible with Windows Photo Gallery.

[This document](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/change-the-date-and-time-a-picture-was-taken) outlines the process.

Or this picture.

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: Thanks, but this is for Windows Vista, not Windows 8/8.1, which does not have the Windows Photo Gallery program.

Comment: It should be on Windows 8 as well. I know Windows 7 has it, except it's just called Photo Gallery. [Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/photo-gallery#photogallery=overview) is a download link.

Comment: Quite annoying that in the default way you can only change the date itself an not the time. Very helpful answer, especially including the download link.

Comment: This is no longer available. "Windows Essentials 2012 suite reached end of support on January 10, 2017"

Answer (score 0):

There's a little free app that can change or modify time/date :

[EXIFeditor](http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php/850f7e10b469d26f9934212caf1e5ea8/56f12e6a/7b54/3/1?tsf=0)

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

To change EXIF-Data, I use [GeoSetter](http://alternativeto.net/software/geosetter/).